# Colocar legenda dinamica em grafico com ChartJS?

Tags: java, chartjs, chart

Estou tentando colocar legendas de forma dinâmica no meu gráfico, entretanto todos os exemplos que vi na Internet até agora são voltados para a parte de frontend (com HTML ou JavaScript), enquanto que no meu caso todo o processo é feito no backend.

Envio o meu `map` (que tem todas as informações) para um método auxilar. Este irá desenhar o gráfico e retornará o `pieDataset` já montado, para ser carregado na página.

Como posso colocar ao lado ou abaixo uma legenda referente ao que cada cor representa?

Código que gera o gráfico:

```
  public PieDataset drawsGraphic(Map<String, BigDecimal> map, PieData data) {
        PieDataset pieDataset = new PieDataset();
        BigDecimal salesCount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            salesCount = salesCount.add(map.get(key));
        }
        int colorCount = 0;
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            pieDataset.addData(percentageCalculatorByBilling(map.get(key), salesCount));
            pieDataset.addBackgroundColor(ChartUtil.colors[colorCount++]);
            data.addLabel(key);
        }
        return pieDataset;
    }
```

Resultado final:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]